# Removing unused credit card from CIBIL credit report

Tags: credit-card, india, banking, credit-score, credit

I used to hold an **ABN Amro(Now RBS)** co-branded credit card back in 2008. After using it for a period, I realized that the card was no good for my needs. I called up the customer care and asked for the account closure. Believing that the account was closed, I destroyed the card and any related documentation accompanying it.

Recently I got by CIBIL report generated and to my astonishment I find the card to be still actively listed. I can't get this card closed as I have no details with me. I do remember the online banking userid but the ABN amro site no longer exists and the RBS site doesn't recognize it. Following are my questions:

- Does the presence of unused cards adversely affect my credit score?
- Is there a way to get this card details removed from CIBIL report, other than that from the bank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the presence of unused cards adversely affect my credit score?

Ifs its a old card, it would in fact result in increased score as the line is open for longer period and the overall credit limit is increased [factoring in the limit of this unused card]. However there could be fraud, etc and hence it would be advisable for you to get this cancelled.

> Is there a way to get this card details removed from CIBIL report, other than that from the bank?

Not in this case. The only way to get this removed would be by contacting your Bank and requesting for closure.

Answer (score 1):

Per Clark Howard you should not close old credit cards.  Instead use them twice a year to keep them in your mix.  30% of your credit score is based on Available credit (% of available credit).  So it very important to keep cards with high limits around if there is no annual fee.  You can leapfrog credit cards by getting a new card then closing this one.  Your credit score will only go down a little do to the average credit age going down.